# Using Blue green deploy for components which are NOT API server (in kubernetes)

Tags: deployment, amazon-eks, argocd, blue-green-deployment

Need to know how can I implement Blue-Green deployments in kubernetes deployment which are just a worker process i.e. it is not behind service and ingress instead using the redis/kafka to fetch the jobs to be processed.

just want to know if there is any straightforward way in argoCD or not. I know there are difficult ways to achieve it but want some straight-forward solution.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You used the kubernetes tag which reads "KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here."

Comment: @possum a wrong tag make it enough for downvote and voting for close? what about just the question? Isn't it still valid?

Comment: It's not actually valid.  If you read that tag, and more importantly, understand what stackoverflow is about, you shouldn't be asking about deployments about k8s.  Because this is a venue about programming and software development, not your personal devops support.

Comment: since when did STOF stop becoming a place for DevOps questions? doesn't that come under engineering? and what do you mean by `programming and software development` .. leetcode questions?